# Reindex on elasticsearch v2.1.0 on Swisscom Application Cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, swisscomdev

I want to reindex data from an existing index on the Swisscom Application Cloud to a new one (have to make adjustments to the mapping). I saw that from version 2.3.0 on there is a reindex API. But since the elasticsearch version on the appcloud is 2.1.0, i have no clue how to reindex my data. Do you have any suggestions how to proceed? And will there be an elasticsearch upgrade in the near future?

Comment: Sorry, edited my question. Thought because I used our dev tag i could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document in elasticsearch are immutable. Reindexing a document consist of the following steps:

- Retrieve the JSON (that you want to reindex)
- Change it
- Delete the old document
- Index a new document

In your case you want to reindex your whole index, so I suggest that you use the scan API to retrieve all your old document and reindex it into your new index: [Scan API documentation for reindexing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wrote a simple python script to retrive my data with the get API and now i can index it again into a new one. I think the scan API is not avaiable with ES version 2.1 but I think it works with my approach!

Comment: You should upgrade you ES a lot of cool features has been implemented!

Comment: I'd love to but I use an ELK service on a application cloud so I have no influence on upgrades. Locally I work with v5.5!